# How to prevent RFC5322.From header spoofing

Tags: smtp, spf, dkim, spoofing, dmarc

I have an email service in domain `example.com`. How can I protect it from spoofing USER email addresses in `From` header?

Scenario:

> Attacker sends email from malory@example.com - connect to my SMTP service, authenticate correctly as malory and sends message with header `From: alice@example.com`

SPF can't help, because attacker use my legitimate SMTP service, have own account and correctly authenticate.

DKIM can't help either, from the same reasons - attacker uses real, legitimate email account, so massage have proper digital signatures.

DMARC can't help, because only checks if envelope and RFC5322.From domains   matches, not user accounts.

Is there any way to check if an envelope and `From` WHOLE addresses matches? How can I protect properly SMTP service against spoofing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is up to your mail server settings, validating from addresses. Mailinabox.email includes this in its standard config using postfix, so maybe look at their config.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent spoofing in your case, your email server example.com would have to include a DKIM-Signature message header that resolves to your own domain. This would only work if the private encryption key used is unique to your organization and not shared among service users like you pointed out.

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple; s=subdomain; d=mydomain.com; ...
```

To accomplish this, your email server would need to provide you with the public key or publish the it on their own domain. Using the latter case, you would point to the public key using a DNS CNAME record.

```
TXT subdomain._domainkey.mydomain.com "p=..."
```

OR

```
CNAME subdomain._domainkey.mydomain.com uniqueid.xxx.example.com
```

Comment: It  won't help. malory@example.com and alice@example.com share same certificate for domain example.com in DKIM signature.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question Scenario: Attacker sends email from malory@example.com - connect to my SMTP service, **authenticate correctly as malory and sends message with header From: alice@example.com**.

SPF,DKIM or DMARC won't help you. You must check Mail From in [evelope header](https://www.mybluelinux.com/what-is-email-envelope-and-email-header/) and FROM in [email header](https://www.mybluelinux.com/what-is-email-envelope-and-email-header/) on MTA layer.

You can write own python script to compare this two headers. And add that script as content inspection to postfix MTA.